# Undefined method for save_screenshot for Capybara and Poltergeist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, integration-testing, poltergeist

I'm using capybara (1.1.4), poltergeist (1.0.2) and rails (3.2.13). I'm trying to take a screenshot to debug some errors I'm getting. However, both the capybara and poltergeist save screenshot methods aren't working. When I do poltergeist (and all my tests have js: true), I get this:

```
Failure/Error: save_screenshot('test.png')
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `save_screenshot' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x007fb5fcce3178>
```

When I do the Capybara way I get this:

```
Failure/Error: page.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `save_screenshot' for #<Capybara::Session>
```

I'm completely stumped on why this isn't working and googling has been completely unhelpful. If you need more info, just ask and I'll respond ASAP. I'd really appreciate the help!

Comment: Is the Capybara::DSL included here? Log out `page` to check. Otherwise be sure to...

require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
require 'nokogiri'

Comment: Not sure what you mean by log out page. But even though I required spec_helper.rb and they're all required in there, I put in all the requires and it still didn't work.

Comment: `page` refers to the Capybara instance/session.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I noticed you stated you were on [poltergeist 1.0.2](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist/tree/v1.0.2#taking-screenshots) yet the syntax you are using is from a [later version](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist/tree/v1.3.0). Try upgrading to version 1.3.0.

Comment: This worked thanks! It's not a great solution as it also updates Capybara which messes up a bunch of tests but it does allow for me to take snapshots.